# Size of Folders

Tags: windows

I would like to delete all empty folders in a folder without having to open all of them. Unfortunately the size is not displayed next to the folder name. I already tried to adjust it under "options" but it is still not working.
Would anyone know how to do display the size?
Thank you!

Comment: See [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using `tree` function: on my PC I have created three subfolders and only one of them contains a file. The result of the `tree` command looks as follows:

```
C:\Temp_Folder>tree /F /A
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 261B-B97E
C:.
|   Ga_van_A_naar_B_in_de_VS.png
|   landen
|
+---tralala
|       test.txt
|
+---tralalala
\---tralalalala
```

As you see, when the next directory comes directly on the next line, this means your directory is empty (you need `/F` to see the files inside the directories for verifying they're empty or not).